# Parse JSON with Gson. Difficult JSON structure without keys

Tags: java, android, json, gson

How can I create the correct object for the following structure?

JSON without any keys and with arrays in arrays in arrays:

```
   {
    "1": [
          [
             [1.111, 2.222]
             [1.111, 2.222]
             ...
          ],
          [
             [1.111, 2.222]
             ...
          ]
       ],
    "2": [
          [
             [1.111, 2.222]
             ...
          ],
          [
             [1.111, 2.222]
             ...
          ]
       ],
    ...
    }
```

Comment: What are you having trouble with? What don't you understand? can you explain each nested type in the JSON object?

Comment: i cant create correct object for deserializing. I have error "Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 7" when use Map<String, Area[]>, where Area - class with arrays of floats

Comment: "..." means similar dynamic continuation

Comment: oh, sorry for this. Its JsonView plugin for chrome. I consider that it is strings while trying to parse this json

Comment: may be you could consider explaining what a `Area` is? like, post the code you are using.

Comment: solution found! Ill post it here in a few moments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I won't give you the code solution, but I will explain your format. The JSON format is explained in detail [here](http://www.json.org/).

You have

```
{
"1": [
      [
         [1.111, 2.222]
         [1.111, 2.222]
         ...
      ],
      [
         [1.111, 2.222]
         ...
      ]
   ],...
```

Your root element is a JSON object. It contains a number of pairs. Each pair `("1": ...)` has a value that is a JSON array `[...]`. Each of these JSON arrays contains element which are JSON arrays `[...]`. These JSON arrays finally contain elements which are JSON number primitives `[12.34]`.

So your JSON has the following levels (number between parenthesis is conceptual nested level)

```
Object (0)
   name -> Array (1) of Arrays (2)
            -> Array (2) of Arrays (3)
                -> Array (3) of number primitives
```

This could be mapped to a `Map<String, List<List<List<Double>>>>` as you have three nested levels of arrays.

If you have a custom class, that could work too, but it will be hard to map the root pair names as you can't have dynamic field names in Java classes. That's why I suggest a `Map` above.

Alternatively, you could just parse the JSON as a [`com.google.gson.JsonObject`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.2.3/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonObject.html) and traverse the object structure to get the element you want.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem but i have a little bit diffrent JSON and i have problem to use your solution with Map. Example (Map>).

My JSON structure:

```
{
   "2019-05-26": {
        "lastUpdate": "2019-05-26 06:05:02",
        "routes":[
            {
              "routeId": 107,
              "agencyId": 18
            },
            {
              "routeId": 222,
              "agencyId": 22
            }
       ]
    },
"2019-05-27": {
        "lastUpdate": "2019-05-27 06:05:02",
        "routes":[
            {
              "routeId": 33,
              "agencyId": 14
            },
            {
              "routeId": 345,
              "agencyId": 2232
            }
       ]
    }
}
```

How to use this JSON ? I would like to parse it to my POJOs.